# Nested dictionary in VBA : Error 457 : this key is already associated with an element of collection

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of dictionary structure in vba

Basically, I start with a 3 column tables :

Product Id | Customer Id | Source

1 | 1 | A

1 | 2 | A

2 | 1 | A

3 | 1 | B

And I want to transform it into a main dictionary "DicByUser" where the keys are the user ids and the items are another dictionary that contain as keys the products visited by a client and as item the source code.

In that case, I would have

DicByUser=  { 1 : { 1 : A , 2 : A, 3 : B}, 2 : {1 : A }}

My approach was to go through all the rows of my initial table then :

with Cid the customer Id,

Pid the product Id,

source the Source

```
If DicByUser.Exists(Cid) Then
    If DicByUser.Item(Cid).Exists(Pid) Then
        'We do something on the item
    Else
        DicByUser.Item(Cid).Add Pid, source
    End If
 Else
    Dim dicotoadd As New Scripting.Dictionary
    dicotoadd.Add Pid, source
    DicByUser.Add Cid, dicotoadd
```

Weirdly, the line before the last gives me the error : vba tells me that

```
Error 457 : this key is already associated with an element of collection
```

Then, if I go in debug mode and I try to display the number of elements in my object dicotoadd, I find 1, while the object was created at the line before.

I believe there is probably a problem in the way I put a dictionary in another one by always giving it the same name, otherwise I don't see why a dictionary that I create one line above can already contain an element

What am I doing wrong in my procedure to create a nested dictionary in vba?

Edit : Solved by changing my code to the following, as suggested by Mat's Mug

```
If DicByUser.Exists(Cid) Then
    If DicByUser.Item(Cid).Exists(Pid) Then
        'We do something on the item
    Else
        DicByUser.Item(Cid).Add Pid, source
    End If
 Else
    Dim dicotoadd As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicotoadd = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dicotoadd.Add Pid, source
    DicByUser.Add Cid, dicotoadd
```

Comment: it seems that dim as new is not properly released after use, try to release it manually ( Set dicotoadd = nothing ), and try to split declaration from instatiation ( dim outside if, and then set dictotoadd = new scripting.dictionary )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic trap.

- The smallest scope for a variable in VBA is procedure-level
- `As New` at procedure scope changes the object's lifetime

Here's a simple example that should enlighten you:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()

    Dim c1 As New Collection 'notice: As New
    c1.Add "TEST"
    Set c1 = Nothing
    c1.Add "this will NOT throw runtime error 91"

    Dim c2 As Collection
    Set c2 = New Collection
    c2.Add "TEST"
    Set c2 = Nothing
    c2.Add "this WILL throw runtime error 91"

End Sub
```

Your code is declaring `DicByUser As New` - the fact that it's inside an `Else` branch doesn't change its scope, it's still local to procedure-scope, and **it's not an executable statement that runs when the Else branch runs**.

Split the declaration and the reference assignment, you'll fix your bug.